# If $A^2=-1_V$, then $V$ is a direct sum of $A$-invariant two dimension subspaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be vector space over a field $F$ with dimension $2m$, If $A$ is a linear transformation of $V$ satisfing $A^2=-1_V$, then $V$ is a direct sum of $A$-invariant two dimension subspaces $V_i's (i=1,2,…, m) $ and $A_ {V_i} =-1_ {V_i}$ for $I=1,2,…, m$?

The following is the similar question in Math-StackExchange:
[A finite dimensional $\Bbb Q$-vector space $V$ is a direct sum of $2$-dimensional $T$-invariant subspaces if $T^2=-I$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612710/a-finite-dimensional-bbb-q-vector-space-v-is-a-direct-sum-of-2-dimensiona)

Comment: If $A_{V_i}=-1_{V_i}$ and $V=\sum_iV_i$ then $A=-1_V$ and $A^2=1_V$.

Comment: Unless the field has characteristic $2$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thank you very much!